# SQLException 00604 & 01003 while calling stored procedure from hibernate named query

Tags: sql, hibernate, stored-procedures, sqlexception, named-query

We are calling a stored procedure ( which calls another inside it) from hibernate.

`Query query = session.getNamedQuery("query_name");
query.setParameter('param', 'value');

query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List returnList = query.list();`

The stored procedure is independently running good  when we run in SQL developer. But we run this through application it is giving **following error**.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

ORA-01003: no statement parsed
```

**Things we tried :**

1. calling a simple stored procedure from hibernate - working well.
2. creating the test case to test the method in which the stored
   procedure (which throws error) is being called - working well.

**Our question is** , why the same query is running good in test case, and not while running thorugh application ?

Any ideas?

**Update**
It was my fault, i was passing the arguments in-correctly. Just swapped the first tow arguments. To anybody facing this issue, please check your argument ordering in the named query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault, i was passing the arguments in-correctly. Just swapped the first tow arguments. To anybody facing this issue, please check your argument ordering in the named query.